# random size objects c++

Tags: c++, object, random

I've been trying to complete a programming exercise  which involves allocating 10,000 objects of random sizes in the [1000:0)-byte range using new, the purpose is to time how long it takes new to allocate the objects and how long it takes delete to deallocate them. I was wondering what's the best way to get objects of random sizes? I thought of one method but I'm not sure if its correct:

```
// Object of varying size
class Object {
public:
    Object(int num_bytes)  { vc.resize(num_bytes); }
    vector<char> vc;  // char is 1 byte
};

int n = 10000;  // number of Objects to allocate

vector<Object*> pointers;

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int size = randint(1, 1000);    // random number between 1 and 1000
    Object* p = new Object(size);
    pointers.push_back(p);  // keep pointers to Objects in vector so 
                                        // can later deallocate
}
```

Comment: It depends on your usage of the word `object` - wouldn't an array of `char`s suffice?

Comment: All instances of `Object` will be the same size. `std::vector` allocates its memory with a separate allocation.

Comment: A `char` is indeed a "byte" in standard C++. The problem is that in standard C++ a "byte" is really *at least* 8 bits long. It's not guaranteed to be 8 bits (it could be more).

Comment: Hi thanks for your replies so will using a random sized array of chars allocated using new work?

Comment: @FredLarson: That's okay; the `Object` destruction is pretty trivial. What you're really doing here is comparatively timing the destruction of the vectors themselves, just slightly indirectly.

Comment: @Jefffrey: It's not just in standard C++ that "byte" is not synonymous with "octet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int size = randint(1, 1000);    // random number between 1 and 1000
    char* p = new char[size];
    pointers.push_back(p);
}
```

I think this code will do what you need.

Comment: The vector resize will increase only the internally allocated buffers for the vector and not the allocated memory for "Object"

Answer (score 2):

Just say no to raw loops and raw pointers that own resources ([Live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8623bbc2dd56aa9)):

```
const int n = 10000;  // number of Objects to allocate

std::mt19937 engine{std::random_device{}()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist(1, 1000);

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>> pointers;
pointers.reserve(n);

std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(pointers), n, [&]{
    return std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char [dist(engine)]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is allocating char arrays:

```
char *obj = new char[numberOfBytes];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply yea that looks like a better solution than using a class and vector member